# Rails - how to write an index view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, indexing, constants

I'm having trouble figuring out how to display an index.

In my organisation requests view folder, I have a file called index.html.erb.

In that file, I'm trying to list each organisation request. I've tried each of the following formulations:

```
<% OrganisationRequest.each do |OrgReq| %>
<% organisation_request.each do |OrgReq| %>
<% @organisation_request.each do |OrgReq| %>
<% @organisation_requests.each do |OrgReq| %>
```

In each case, I get an error that says:

```
formal argument cannot be a constant
```

I thought a constant meant something beginning with a capital letter. 3 of the above attempts don't begin with a capital letter.

It's also confusing to me since in my user index, I have <% User.each %> and I don't get an error message.

Can anyone see what's gone wrong? How do I ask for a list of objects?

Comment: Your variable `OrgReq` is a constant. Try something like `org_req`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your data and view right, you should be able to fix with:

```
<% @organisation_requests.each do |org_req| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If we stick Rails conventions, we'd say that, you have a OrganisationRequests controller, has such content.

```
class OrganisationRequestsController < ApplicationController
...
  def index
    @your_local_variable = OrganisationRequest.find(...)   
  end
...
end
```

That is to say, you need to use, `@your_local_variable` inside view file.

```
<% @your_local_variable.each do |o| %>
 ....
<% end %>
```

If the variable inside index action is `@organisation_requests`, use that.